# package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist

Tags: maven

i get package org.springframework.stereotype error as im running mvn install.
even in .m2 folder there is that package.

error showing me tho this line of code :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
```

dependencies are :

```
<springVersion>4.1.1.RELEASE</springVersion>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
```

is there something i missed ?

UPDATE

here is full lines of error i get :

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project mynewProject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/mynewProject/src/main/java/com/web/server/domain/service/WebServiceImpl.java:[17,38] package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/mynewProject/src/main/java/com/web/server/domain/service/WebServiceImpl.java:[25,2] cannot find symbol
```

Comment: Can you include a bit more of the error message? The class `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` is contained in the spring-context dependency, which you have correctly defined. Without more information it is hard to help any further.

Comment: see my update. full error message. I dont know what more could i include

Answer (score 17):

I got similar issues when on my standalone java program when running on java 8 and spring 4.x.

For some reason, i don't see spring-context in the referenced Jars of the project. It should be automatically referenced by maven, but I did not see that happening.

**Solution** : I added the spring-context dependency manually in the pom.xml and my error is fixed.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Solved it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I needed to change the scope-tag to 'compile' instead of 'runtime', and the error went away.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me fix build error in legacy code.

Answer (score 4):

All the dependencies should be within

```
<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

... or your code will continue throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes error is just in IDE!

Try **Build or Clean** your project to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a wrong Maven version configured in the IDE. Upgrading the version solved my problem.